# Can round trip flights be cheaper than one-way flights?

Tags: air-travel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [One-way versus return airfare tickets](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11501/one-way-versus-return-airfare-tickets)

I'm looking for plane trips that would suit me if I studied abroad in the US.

I searched up the flight I'd take: SVG - ATL, and was amazed to see the prices were minimum $1500 for a one-way flight in August. I then checked what the price would be for a round-trip flight, from 12. Aug to 02. Dec, and suddenly the price sunk to $1175 in total! I repeated the search on another site, and saw that they found an even cheaper round flight of around $903.

So, I'm wondering, am I misunderstanding something, or is it really cheaper with round flights? How come??

Comment: Yes, I think this is a duplicate too