# Not using my daughter's round trip ticket

Tags: air-travel, usa

My daughter is starting school in the US (we stay in Thailand) and my wife and I would like to accompany her back. There is a much better deal if we buy round trip tickets, but flying back would only be my wife and myself (contenting through China) . What will happen if my daughter doesn't use her ticket to return with us?

Comment: This specific case seems to be about multiple people on the same booking, and some dumping a leg of the flight while others use it.

Comment: I think the only difference is that they're all on the same booking, so addressing if her not taking it would affect the others would be worthwhile.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it fair to buy a return ticket I know I will never use just because it's cheaper?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/12873/is-it-fair-to-buy-a-return-ticket-i-know-i-will-never-use-just-because-its-chea)

Comment: A group ticket where only one of the members has been hospitalized or detained or killed and can't participate on the back leg should not be that unusual.

Answer (score 4):

You'll simply forfeit the return ticket for your daughter.  It might be smart to try to book her ticket with a far-away return date if it doesn't cost extra--maybe she'll come to Thailand a year from now?

If you're wondering if the airline will prevent you from boarding without your daughter present: no, they shouldn't have any reason to do that.