# Round trip tickets much cheaper than one ways, considering purposely missing layover?

Tags: air-travel, layovers, missed-flights

Round trip tickets seem much cheaper than setting up multicity one way in and one way out from a different city...  It is looking like it is cheaper to buy round trip tickets going to/from my final exit city, then bail out onto another plane on the layover in the same country, much closer to the first city I want to go to, then end up in my exit city, taking the exit flight out.  Has anyone done this before?  Would having a flight arranged in the layover city attract any unwanted attention?

Edit:

I want to enter Beijing and leave out of Hong Kong.  It looks cheaper to round trip it to Hong Kong and bail out in Shanghai on the layover.

Both tickets would be used, this is not a duplicate as suggested.  I just didn't want to finish the entire first leg of the journey.   Since the return flight would be canceled as in the answer I guess it won't work.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your proposed itinerary.  Can you give a concrete example?

Comment: Anyway, the thing that usually goes wrong in these schemes is that if you have an itinerary consisting of multiple flights, and you skip one of them, then the airline will typically cancel all your remaining flights on that itinerary, often without a refund.

Comment: You might also like to have a look at your airline's contract of carriage - there is usually a long section on "prohibited ticketing practices".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it fair to buy a return ticket I know I will never use just because it's cheaper?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/12873/is-it-fair-to-buy-a-return-ticket-i-know-i-will-never-use-just-because-its-chea) or http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11501/one-way-versus-return-airfare-tickets or any number of similar questions in the related sidebar. Alternatively, it should be closed because it's not clear what's being asked.

Comment: @NateEldredge Updated

Comment: Looks like the duplicate flag is wrong for this one. OP is asking about "hidden city" ticketing, not one-way of return flight.

Comment: Even with your edit, it's really not clear what ticket(s) you would buy, and what flights you would actually use and which ones you wouldn't. Can you clarify? Are you saying that it would be cheaper to book Hong Kong-Shanghai-Beijing (and return) than Hong Kong-Shanghai (and return), so you want to book HK-Shanghai-Beijing and use only Hong Kong-Shanghai?

Comment: It is not a duplicate, I wanted to use both tickets, just not complete the entire first leg.

Comment: @RobC - there is no "both tickets" for a round trip - it's all on one ticket, and if you skip on part of the first leg, they cancel the rest of the journey. If you get two singles though (see the dupe on "hidden city"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have similar tricks done several times, and the airlines are not happy about it, but it works perfectly fine.

Be aware though that:

1. If you check luggage, you might *not* be able to check it to an intermediate airport only (they might just not offer that - it is only good for exactly this trick)
2. You ***lose all further legs on this ticket***, without reimbursement. Yes, that includes your return trip. So you need to buy *two* round-trip tickets, one for each way, and repeat the trick each time (or take a normal one-way ticket for one of the directions if you can't make it work).

if these are not an issue for you, go ahead.

Comment: you might be right, it is anecdotal. An airline employee once told me that they know the trick and don't like it, but yes, if you are not a FF, they probably wouldn't know, how could they. I removed it.