# Why is this one-way flight more expensive than round trip?

Tags: air-travel

Why is this one way flight from Paris to Toronto is significantly more expensive than the same trip that includes a round trip? If anything the round trip should be more expensive because it's the same as the one-way trip and more! Also, why are these economy flights so expensive? Usually it's 1/3rd of the price.

[image: one-way flight]

[image: round trip]

Comment: The second answer in this thread may she'd some light on this for ya! Hope it helps!        https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/12873/is-it-fair-to-buy-a-return-ticket-i-know-i-will-never-use-just-because-its-chea

Comment: Compare the conditions for cancellations and exchanges. The first one is fully flexible. The second one is completely inflexible.

Comment: @jcaron That's true for this particular flight, but I've seen the same thing happen with BA where the conditions were identical (both inflexible) yet direct A > B was x3 the price of direct A > B then direct B > A

Comment: Look at "economy standard" London -> Amman with BA, for example. One way 21st Sept is £1,326. The exact same flight, with the exact same "economy standard" terms, but adding a return leg on 28th Sept, is £312 for the outward leg, totalling around £600 for both legs, less than half the outbound flight if bought alone.

Comment: @user568458 "Economy standard" is the service class (cabin+checked luggage+priority), not the fare. The one-way flight in your London-Amman example is a Y fare (the full fare, fully flexible, refundable and exchangeable with no penalty). The return flight uses fare classes N and V, is not refundable at all, and has a £150 fee for any changes. There are probably also differences in how many frequent flyer miles you get in each case.

Comment: @ReddHerring I got a headache and no answers after reading that post. The only unsatisfying answer I got is "It's complicated".

Comment: $2000 one way? Yikes! I can get a TRN-NYC round trip flight for €350... and I'm sure NYC-YYZ in economy doesn't cost $1600.