# Search engine for stop over possibilites

Tags: air-travel, new-zealand, stopovers, flight-search-engines

I am planning a flight from Auckland to Europe and am trying to find out which places are convenient to stop over. I once knew a website where you can simply enter the two airports, and it shows you all the possible stop overs you can have with different airlines, but I  can't find this site anymore. The site should be less about finding cheap flights (which would be an awesome bonus, of course) but more about finding places to visit in between.
Any idea where to find something like this?

Comment: I don't know any website specifically designed to look for stopovers but many search engines listed in http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26780/is-there-a-flight-search-engine-that-combines-flights-from-different-airlines/26888#26888 or http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/730/how-can-i-do-a-broad-search-for-flights do offer a way to filter based on intermediate stops.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like [Rome2Rio](http://rome2rio.com/)?  Doesn't show you *all* the possibilities, mind you, but a sensible subset, and also works in trains, buses, ferries etc when applicable.

Comment: Wow! What an awesome page. Thanks for showing. Not exactly what i was looking for, but pretty cool.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I've created a [Stopover Search Engine](http://www.questorganizer.com/) to find cheapest stopovers between two places. For every flight it presents 5 destinations which you can visit on the way and tries to make it cheaper or the same price as RT flights would be. Hopefully it's what you were lookig for :)

Answer (score 1):

Also checkout [Hipmunk.com](http://www.hipmunk.com/) they certainly show a variety of options so should show you which stops are available to you between certain stops and on what airlines. Mind you they do not have all the airlines but it should give you some idea.

Comment: This offers a nice overview, too. Thanks for the link