# Stop over enroute to Johannesburg

Tags: south-africa, stopovers

I am traveling from Seattle to Johannesburg in September and would like to stop over somewhere for a few days to break up the 25 hour flight.  Where would you stop and how can I book these flights without breaking the bank

Comment: Welcome! It's worth having a look at the [help] - this is a Q&A site for objective answers, a bit different to most travel forums. I'm putting this on hold at present.

Comment: Also you've said 25 hours, but haven't said what that route is? I know there are much longer routes that would affect the stopover options as well if you ruled them out.

Comment: My 'normal' trip between Atlanta & Cape Town typically includes a stop in London and I often find this to be less expensive than options.

Comment: Some of the sites suggested under [Search engine for stop over possibilites](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/31624/search-engine-for-stop-over-possibilites?rq=1) would be a good place to start

Comment: One possibility is Seattle to LAX then pick up Emirates to Dubai. It does make the last flight (Dubai to J'berg longish). I don't know how Emirates feels about a multi-day stopover. The A380 is a very nice plane.