# Search engine allowing stopovers longer than 24 hours, flexible dates and several destinations

Tags: layovers, connecting-flights, flight-search-engines, stopovers

A related question may be this one: [How can I do a "broad" search for flights?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/730/how-can-i-do-a-broad-search-for-flights), but it's a quite broad question (as the title suggests haha)

Maybe the most similar question is this one: [Search engine for stop over possibilites](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/31624/search-engine-for-stop-over-possibilites). That problem is solved by search engines like https://www.cleverlayover.com/, but it doesn't allow to enter several origins and destinations (typically cities with airports close by), or several dates.

Other search engines like https://kiwi.com/ or https://www.azair.com/ doesn't allow to enter a longer than 24 hours stopover.

The favourite solution or manual workaround so far is using azair.com to check the common (short) layover stop cities after selecting several dates and cities. Then writing down the most repeated stop cities. Then booking flights with those cities as stop overs independently.

**Any search engine that does all that work automatically?**

---

**UPDATE**

Reading comments and answers, the following should help to understand the question better:

the stopover city is not so important, but it's a good thing to have options. It's an opportunity to give a short visit to a city that didn't attract me, so I probably would visit it otherwise. Everything is variable in different levels:

- Origin airport including near airports
- Stop airport anywhere in the world
- Destination airport including near airports.

Comment: Is the stopover city important to you? It’s unclear what is fixed or variable in your search.

Comment: @jcaron the stopover city is not so important, but it's a good thing to have options. It's an opportunity to give a short visit to a city that didn't attract me, so I probably would visit it otherwise. Everything is variable in different levels: origin airport including near airports, stop airport anywhere in the world, destination airport including near airports. Hope that clarifies. Thanks for your interest!

Answer (score 3):

You need Nomad service ([kiwi.com/nomad](https://www.kiwi.com/en/nomad/)) of the Kiwi that allows up to 60 days of layover, multiple stops and connecting flights from different airlines.

Candidates for stopover destinations can be found in the cleverlayover, Kayak or Skyscanner with 1+ layovers filter prior the detailed search in the Nomad.

Example:
[image]

Comment: Interesting tool. I didn't know it. Anyway, it solves a different matter as I MUST choose the stop city (I cannot select anywhere as the stop city)

Comment: Than you just need to find the candidates first, pick the ones you are interested in and do the final search in Nomad with your limitations. Added to the answer.
It might be good to edit your question to define what exactly are you looking for instead of linking to similar questions. I did not get it at first.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is less one involving search engines and more involving airline ticketing rules. It's very rare to find an airline that allows stopovers of more than 24 hours on a single ticket. Most allow fewer for domestic flights and about 24 hours for international flights (there are, of course, exceptions).

By limiting their output to what you're actually allowed to book these search engines are catering to customers who want to purchase their travel all on one ticket. If you want longer stopovers then, with a few exceptions, you'll need either to book multi-city tickets (via ITA Matrix or something similar) or just simply use your favorite search engine to book multiple tickets.

Comment: I don't expect to buy the same ticket with the same airline. The favourite solution or manual workaround so far I describe at the end of the question uses my favourite search engine to book multiple tickets manually. But this question is asking if you know a search engine to do it automatically.

Comment: A stopover is nearly be definition over 24 hours. Under that it’s a layover. Many airlines allow stopovers, but not necessarily on all fares. Some are actually famous for offering special deals with hotels etc. for stopovers. CX was famous for that, some Gulf airlines as well as TK do the same, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

https://matrix.itasoftware.com allows each leg of a multi city itinerary to have a range of departure date OR arrival date.  Google purchased ITA, so I suspect that Google Flights can also do something similar.

Also, in some of the searches I have made in other search engines, I have seen layovers of longer than a day shown, but I don't recall which.

Comment: As far as I know, ITA Matrix does not include airlines like Ryanair. It's a really nice tool for long international flights though. Also, I don't think it includes an option for long layovers. After selecting the flight you can search for the text: UNLIMITED STOPOVERS PERMITTED ON THE PRICING UNIT though

Answer (score 1):

I've been using https://www.stopo.org/ and it's pretty cool for searching flights with long stopovers when you don't know where to stopover

Comment: hi @jonnothegangster, welcome to Travel Stack Exchange! Are you affiliated with stopo.org?

Comment: no i am not affiliated

Comment: Hi. Thanks for sharing! I've given it a try. It would be much cooler if the flights between the origin to stopover is a direct flight. And also the flight from the stopover and destination is a direct flight. I mean, in the search I did to test it, from the stopover to the final destination there are 3 layovers and 34h total... Which still could be OK in the past. But now with the crazy COVID regulation, too many layovers are a headache for me. Thanks for sharing anyway and very interesting idea! Hope they add that feature of only direct flights soon :D