# How can I book flights online with separate airlines?

Tags: budget, flight-search-engines, connecting-flights

I want to travel to Ibiza again this summer. I want to go there from Tehran, Iran via connecting flights. For example, I would like to fly from Tehran to Frankfurt on Lufthansa, and then from Frankfurt to Ibiza on Ryan Air. What websites can I use to do this?

Comment: BIG WARNING: The Frankfurt->Ibiza Ryanair flight leaves from the "Frankfurt Hahn" airport, which is over 100 miles away from the big airport in Frankfurt that Lufthansa serves. It takes several hours to travel between these airports.

Comment: @DCTLib I wonder why they called it "Frankfurt Hahn" in the first place. Even Luxembourg is closer to it than Frankfurt.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev As per Wiki, it says the airport was renamed from Hahn to Frankfurt Hahn when Ryan started operating there. This caused a legal dispute from Lufthansa and Ryan Air citing a Frankfurt Hahn a misdirection to Frankfurt. Ryan Air advertises flights as to and from Frankfurt on its ads. But Ryan Air won and hence the name remained the same.

Comment: @DCTLib it seems that it's actually about 115 km by road, which is about 71 miles, and that the drive time is around 70 minutes without traffic.

Comment: @phoog Ok, fine - https://www.luftlinie.org/Frankfurt-Hahn/Frankfurt fooled me here by for some reason by showing miles instead of kilometers earlier today (and me not noticing that this is between the city centers). But it's highly unlikely that the OP would consider a one-way car rental to be a good idea (and then, one would need to add some time for the rental formalities as well). Including time to allow for traffic, the "multiple hours" at least still applies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a flight search engine that combines flights from different airlines?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26780/is-there-a-flight-search-engine-that-combines-flights-from-different-airlines) and also relevant: [How can I do a “broad” search for flights?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/730/32134)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As stated in [Hilmar's answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/97732/how-can-i-online-book-flights-with-separate-airlines/97733#97733) there needs to be some arrangement (code share) between both airlines to book it as a single ticket.

When those arrangements don't exist, one option is still to make this booking as two separate tickets on your own in which case you bear the risk of missing your connection.

A third option is to book a connecting flight through [Kiwi.com](https://www.kiwi.com/us/search/tehran-iran/ibiza-ibiza-spain/2017-09-01_2017-09-30/2-10?sortBy=price), a site which specializes in selling unofficial connections between airlines who don't have agreements with each other. In this case Kiwi.com includes insurance under the name of the "[Kiwi.com Guarantee](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/134484/what-does-the-kiwi-com-guarantee-cover)." In case you miss the connecting flight, you contact them and they have staff that will rebook you onto the next best option.

[image: Kiwi.com results]

For any unofficial connection (making your own two bookings or via Kiwi.com) also note that there may be additional visa requirements for the airport you're transferring at. If you have checked luggage you may have to leave the secure area of the airport and pick it up at baggage claim and recheck it when switching airlines. Some airlines do have interlining agreements where they can forward baggage between each other, so it's always worth asking them if. Even if you have just a carry-on you may also have to leave the secure area to access check-in for the connecting flight if you're not able to do it online or at a transfer desk.

Comment: This answer is missing any mention of *interlining* with regards to baggage.   Many airlines that do not codeshare do interline.

Answer (score 12):

You have to make two individual bookings, you can't book this on a single ticket.

You can make each booking at any of the typical websites: Lufthansa.com ryanair.com, kayak.com, expedia.com, orbitz.com, hipmunk.com, google flights etc.

Please note that you are responsible for any missed connections: if your flight from Teheran is late and you miss the flight with Ryan Air, you may have to buy a new ticket or get stuck in Frankfurt. Make sure you have plenty of time.

Please note also that Ryan Air often uses Frankfurt Hahn Airport. That's a marketing ploy: Frankfurt Hahn is about two hours away from Frankfurt and closer to Luxemburg than to Frankfurt. Make sure you book Frankfurt International Airport (FRA) and not Frankfurt Hahn (HHN).

Comment: The bit about HHN is important. It's in the middle of nowhere.

Comment: And if you are planning to take public transport to/from the HHN airport, there are no services related to DB. Hence even if you have the ticket for the region, you need to buy an additional ticket to the airport for a private bus service.( ~18 Euro one way)

Answer (score 8):

There is a difference between true "connecting flights", which are arranged as one booking, and buying several different tickets and pretending that they are connected flights.

The exact itinerary you gave is not bookable as connecting flights. (See [**Hilmar**'s answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/97733/29377) for details.) This is because RyanAir does not cooperate with any other carriers. You have to buy the tickets separately.

For true connecting flights, even between different carriers, it is straightforward to book either through one of the airlines directly or through a travel agent. I had a look and you can buy a seven day return ticket from IKA to IBZ for 500 USD leaving next week on British Airways and Iberia as a single ticket. This can be booked on Expedia.com or any major internet travel site.

Comment: Technically, Ryanair do cooperate with other carriers now http://www.independent.ie/business/irish/ryanair-to-sell-long-haul-flights-with-air-europa-35746741.html, but they don't offer this connection.

Comment: @CarlfromBusbud To my knowledge, they are only reselling UX flights on their website. They aren't actually offering connections yet, just promising they will in the future—something they promise whenever their free well of publicity dries up.

Comment: (+1) AFAIK, Ryanair does not offer connections between their own flights.