# Flights - Direct in one direction, but with at least 1 stopover on the other?

Tags: air-travel, budget, fares, stopovers, flight-search-engines

1. How can I search for this on my own? I've tried expedia.com, but when you select 1 or 2 stopovers, it assumes that both directions of your journey are either 1 or 2 stopovers.

2. Also, is this truly cheaper than direct flights in both directions?

3. Are there any better alternatives to this plan? Does [One-way versus return airfare tickets](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/11501/13759) imply that it's more expensive to buy 1 single-way for the outbound, then 1 single-way with a stopover for the inbound?

Comment: If you read the linked question that you cite, top answer specifically addresses answers to 2 and 3.  Sometimes it's cheaper, sometimes it's not.

Answer (score 2):

To 1:) This is actually quite simple. For example, the search engine Kayak.com offers this: click on "Multi-city" and just add all the parts of your journey. Only list cities in which you want to leave the airport - there may still be layovers on the individual parts of the journey.

Note that this *will* find airfares that are for return flights (with stop-overs allowed) whenever there exist some for the journey.

Contrary to the post by @fkraiem, my experience is that most airlines websites do not allow to book such trips (so you will have to use one of the agencies listed by kayak or your favorite walk-in agency), or book them in very bad booking classes (so they cost a lot more).

Comment: This is late, but would you happen to be in the US? My experience is mostly with European and Japanese airlines, and all the airlines I know allow you to choose both legs separately.

Comment: @fkraiem Surely you can do this directly on the airline websites, but then you don't get an airfare comparison between different airlines. So if you are looking for a good price, using a search engine such as Kayak makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

A possible way to do 1 is to first use search engines to find out which airlines offer both flights with and without stopovers, and then book directly from the airline's website. Usually, you are able to select both legs separately among all their offered flights.