# Missing a flight - a way around the penalty?

Tags: air-travel

I booked and paid for a round trip non-stop ticket from Brussels to NY and back for my daughter's wedding.  Since then, I found out that I actually have to get there earlier than originally planned.

I figured that's not such  a big problem, I'll get a one way to the states and come back on my original ticket.
Only I was just informed that if I don't take the first flight, they'll cancel my return.

So I looked into a way around this.  They can cancel my first flight for me, for an additional charge, and leave my return flight as is.
The cost of the round trip ticket was $513 USD.  To make the change of cancelling the first leg, they will charge me an additional $2,406.60 USD.
This is absolutely absurd, abusive and dishonest. They already have my money. If I don't occupy that seat, there is no additional cost to them. 
Anyone know of a good way around this?

Comment: And what about change the date of the first leg?

Comment: It might be cheaper to cancel the whole trip then book again with the new dates, are your tickets cancellable ?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to turn a return ticket into a oneway ticket. This is usually a mistake. Can you not change the date of the first leg?

Comment: I had a similar situation few years back. I missed the first leg of the flight (Turkish Air.) and flew few days later with another company from another city. When i  reached the destination i went to the TA office at the airport and they manually 'put back' my return ticket, which i noticed before was removed from their system due to no show on the first flight They charged me no additional cost or anything.

Comment: Not a solution for you, but as an amusing recent example of the extreme lengths people will go to to avoid this sort of thing: http://www.theguardian.com/money/2015/jun/05/student-changes-name-by-deed-poll-to-avoid-220-ryanair-admin-fee

Answer (score 6):

There is (generally speaking) no way around this. In your situation you have four options:

1. Cancel the original ticket and book a new one. This may be useless if the original fare doesn't allow refunds. However it would free up a seat for some other traveler who might need a last-minute ticket.
2. Book a new one-way ticket and alter the original reservation. You've already found out this is prohibitively expensive, since one-way fares can often be more expensive than round-trip fares. The reasons for this are discussed [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11501/one-way-versus-return-airfare-tickets).
3. Alter the date of the original Brussels->NY flight so that you can get there earlier.
4. Ignore the original reservation and get a brand new return ticket.

The airlines are following a certain contract to which you've agreed when booking the ticket. It may or may not be *absurd*, but that's just how modern airlines operate.

Comment: 1 would be preferable to 4. Even if the ticket is in principle non-refundable, you may get lucky. Happened to me once with Lufthansa: a few days after cancelling a "non-refundable" ticket, I unexpectedly received a full refund, down to the last cent. It also seems like common courtesy to let the airline know in advance that you won't make it.