# A refund that I think my agent wants to cheat me on

Tags: refunds, travel-agents, turkish-airlines

I got a return ticket of Turkish Airline from Lagos to Chicago using an agent called ST. KINGS CROWN TRAVELS. I paid #269,248 and left for Chicago on 2nd Nov 2015. I got to chicago and then had the need to cancel my return flight and request for a refund.

This I made known to ST. KINGS CROWN TRAVELS on the 10th Nov and initially I was told that was not possible but was again told that a refund could be done and that they would need the data page of my int'l passport as well as a letter indicating an authorized refund.

By 12th Nov. I was again told by ST. KINGS CROWN TRAVELS that I needed to wait for six weeks before Turkish Airlines could refund me. I waited and by 23rd Dec, ST. KING CROWN TRAVELS told me that my data page as well as the authorization letter was not neccessary anymore and that Turkish Airlines again said I should wait till this week before they refund me.

This afternoon, I got a call from ST. KINGS CROWN TRAVELS and was told Turkish Airlines gave #30,950 as the refund. I dont understand the possibility of that and know for sure that there is no element of truth in that. I didn't collect the money and had told ST. KING CROWN TRAVELS to produce the receipt Turkish Airlines gave to show that that amount is what was paid but since anything can be fabricated, I need you to help me out as to how do I know the exact amount Turkish Airlines gave as the refund or if there is anyone in Turkish Airlines that I can speak with about this.

Comment: Most discounted airfares are not refundable, except perhaps for some taxes collected.  You can call Turkish Airlines and have them look up your booking to discover the fare rules.

Comment: Visit a turkish airlines office or email them, include your ticket number and reservation number and ask them if this was the refund amount issued by them.

Comment: Note that accusing someone of "cheating" without any actual evidence as to what refund you were entitled could be considered libel. You probably want to edit your post and redact the name of the travel agent (especially as this is not relevant to your question).

Answer (score 12):

Without the full details it's impossible to say for sure, but it's very feasible that this refund was correct.

Firstly you need to take into account the fact there was almost certainly a change/cancellation fee. Most airfares (even refundable ones) have them, although the amount can vary dramatically depending on any number of factors including the airline, the country the ticket was bought in, and the actual fare purchased.

Next, you need to take into account the differences between return and one-way fares.  I'd suggest going and reading this answer first then coming back here - [One-way versus return airfare tickets](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11501/one-way-versus-return-airfare-tickets/11504#11504)

OK, back?

When you cancel a ticket half-way through the trip like you did, it will normally trigger a "re-pricing" of the entire ticket - including the flight you've already flown.

In your case, both your outbound and return legs would have originally been "return" based fares, which are normally cheaper than one-way fares.  When you canceled the return, the ticket would have been repriced, but now it's just a one-way ticket, so the price for the leg you've already flown would have gone up to the one-way fare.

To use a simple example, say your original ticket was $200, made of up two "return" legs that were $100 each.  But a one-way fare on the same route might be $150.  And a change fee of $30.

If you cancel part-way through the journey, then it becomes a one-way ticket and they will reprice the outbound trip to be $150.  Add in the $30 change fee, and you're at $180.  You've already paid $200, so you'd get a refund of $20.

Comment: Nicely explained. It's also possible that only the airport tax was refunded. In most cases, airlines give a refund of the airport tax and may be other surcharges if you can cek a flight early. I'm not sure what currency the OP mentioned, but the taxes are about $50 in a return flight with 2 legs.

Answer (score 1):

It happened for me too I had purchased round trip Manila to Colombo in Singapore air line through travel agent cost me 191000LKR, after I cancelled the return Ticket and request to refund but the travel agent refunded me only 47000LKR and they not give me any proof that shows airline refunded only that amount,I have inquired from the airline how much was my refund instead they replied me to get the break down from the travel agent the airline doesn’t care about the passenger who paid the money they support the travel agent...It doesn’t matter even they had paid me less if it’s the policy of the airline but should given me a proof showing how the refund was calculated

Comment: Thanks for your own experience answer, it confirms OP is not the only one with that kind of reaction. It would be more helpful if you can add how it worked out in the end.

Comment: The airline wont deal with you because you are the travel agents customer and not theirs - the travel agent owns you as a customer, and the airline is providing a service to the travel agent, so any customer service you require must come from the travel agent and not the airline.