# BA: "anx9c1s6 type fares"?

Tags: air-travel, british-airways, fares, fare-class

What are "anx9c1s6 type fares", as seen on the following screenshot I got from britishairways.com while making a booking?

[image: britishairways.com screenshot]

(Googling yields zero hits.)

Comment: I can't say for certain but it looks like it might be a big in the website - have you sent that screenshot to BA?

Comment: The last part of the information (‘no earlier than the first sun’) makes no sense either

Comment: @Traveller: I interpret that to simply require Saturday night stay ("[return] no earlier than the first sun[day] after arrival"). That was consistent with the price graph I was shown.

Comment: It looks like a fare code. They are usually printed uppercase, but fare rules are usually printed all upper case, so they probably lowercased all the text including the fare code. It’s a bit long compared to other fare codes, but probably still a possibility. It would be in booking class A, so discounted first class. One would need to check available fare codes on BA to be sure.

Comment: @jcaron: Thanks for the pointer. I think you may be right and this is indeed a lowercased fare basis code. I'd be curious to deconstruct it (beyond it being discounted first class, which indeed it is), but I'm struggling to find any information online on how to decode the rest. Would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: @NPE as far as I know, fare codes have no common logic (beyond the first letter being the booking class), each airline does whatever they want with them, it's just a random identifier that is used to match fares to fare rules (i.e. the same fare rules apply to all fares with the same fare code, whatever the city pair). And obviously some fare management systems allow them to use templates to share rules between several fare codes, hence the condition in the fare rule in your post.

Comment: Whilst not an answer, the following might provide some extra info about how these work - https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11501/why-are-one-way-plane-tickets-more-expensive-than-return-tickets/11504#11504

Answer (score 2):

I spoke with BA over twitter.

> The code would relate to the rules and restrictions on the ticket. If
>   booking via our website, these would be advised at the time of
>   booking. Nearly all flights would have underlying fare types such as
>   this, and as you point out, 'A' fares would usually be restricted
>   First class fares. These would normally have fees attached to change
>   the booking, and may have a fee for cancellation or be non-refundable.

So as suspected, the A is restricted first class, but the rest is related to your specific booking, and they couldn't give more information without more information from your side.

Answer (score 1):

As fare codes, after the first letter, are airline specific and BA does not share the full list with the general public, you may never find the full explanation. You worked out much already by working out you need to stay a Saturday night.

It is a long and complicated code but those are not unlikely, even though they are rare.